# Android correct String can not be converted into JSONObject

Tags: java, android, string, android-json

I have a response coming from the server. When I am trying to convert the String into JSON Object, I am getting an error

```
 Value {
"StatusCode": "000",
"FileURI":"https:///someurl/directory/filename"
} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

The code that I wrote to parse is:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

Where `response` is My String that is coming from server:

```
"{\r\n  \"StatusCode\": \"000\",\r\n  \"FileURI\": \"https://someurl/directory/filename\"\r\n}"
```

can anyone help me out why is it not working.

Comment: Please share the code you are using for conversion.

Comment: `\r\n` maybe? Wild guess

Comment: @WaqarKhan dude when we do `new JSONObject(String)`, it converts the String to JSON

Comment: try json lint to validate your string https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: @ankitpatidar what else do you want.. I am creating a JSON form String. I gave the String, the code to create JSON and the error.. What else do you want to see

Comment: @TheBat this is working fine for me: `String val = "{\r\n  \"StatusCode\": \"000\",\r\n  \"FileURI\": \"https://someurl/directory/filename\"\r\n}";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(val);`

Comment: Exactly @WaqarKhan it is working correctly,

Answer (score 0):

> String str1 = str.replace("\r", "").replace("\n",
>   "").replace("\\"", "");

use this code to unescape \r and \n

after removing you get the origin string

{
  "StatusCode": "000",
  "FileURI": "https://someurl/directory/filename"
}

use this link to test the string https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output